# what is the alternative to chrome.app.isInstalled?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In manifest v2 extension I used
`if (typeof chrome.app.isInstalled !== "undefined") { //do something }` in the content script to check if the extension is installed, since `chrome.app` is now deprecated, it is no longer working. What is the alternative to check if  the extension is installed?

Comment: If the content script runs it already means the extension is installed. Please describe the workflow in more detail.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.